# MongoDb count subarray elements in C# return all time 0

Tags: c#, mongodb

I have a document in my MongoDb database, and I want to write a query to retrieve documents whose array size is greater than 0 (array is not null or empty to be clear).

Here is my C# code givent the fact that `Quotes` is my subarray :

```
internal bool HasQuote(string projectNumber)
{
    var filter = Builders<Entity.Project>.Filter.Eq(x => x.ProjectNumber, projectNumber);
    filter &= Builders<Entity.Project>.Filter.Exists(x => x.Quotes);
    filter &= Builders<Entity.Project>.Filter.SizeGt(x => x.Quotes.Count, 0);

    var res = _mongoCollection.CountDocuments(filter);
    return res > 0;
}
```

Unfortunately the function returns all time `false`. It must be related to the `SizeGt` part, because when I remove this line it is working fine.
I tryed other stuff like `filter &= Builders<Entity.Project>.Filter.Where(x => x.Quotes.Count > 0);` or `filter &= Builders<Entity.Project>.Filter.Exists(x => x.Quotes[0]);`

Comment: Have you tried running the count documents with only first filter to see if you get more than 0 documents...

Comment: @Jawad it does return more than 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**What does SizeGT takes in as parameters?**

`SizeGt(FieldDefinition<TDocument> field, int size);`

which means you have to provide a Field that you need to get a count on.

**What to do to fix your code**

Change the line:

```
filter &= Builders<Entity.Project>.Filter.SizeGt(x => x.Quotes.Count, 0);
```

to this

```
filter &= Builders<Entity.Project>.Filter.SizeGt(x => x.Quotes, 0);
```

Reason you dont provide the Count is because SizeGT knows how to Convert x.Quotes and get a count of it. If you do a count and catch the error, you'll get the error:

> Unable to determine the serialization information for x => Convert(x.Quotes.Count).

I just ran the code above on my list and it came back with correct numbers.